# Pass values from one component to another in react

Tags: reactjs

container.js -

```
//Here we render the recipe details and display add recipe form.   
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AddRecipe from './addrecipe.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={ recipes :[] } 
  this.addRecipe=this.addRecipe.bind(this);
  }

addRecipe (recipe) {
this.setState({ 
  recipes: [...this.state.recipes, recipe]
});
}

componentWillMount(){
this.setState({
  recipes : require('./sample-recipes')
});
} 

home(e){
 window.location='/a';
}

render() {
  return (
   <div className="App">
   <h2>Welcome to the Recipe Book</h2>
   <dl>
   {this.state.recipes.map(recipe => {
    return ( <div key={recipe.name} onClick={this.home}>
      <dt>{recipe.name}</dt>
      <dd>{recipe.ingredient}</dd>
      <div><img src='{recipe.image}' className="image"/></div>
      <hr></hr>
      </div>
      )
  })
 }
 </dl>
 <button className="addButton" onClick={() => 
  {this.setState({ display: !this.state.display })}}>
  Add Recipe
  </button>
  <AddRecipe addRecipe={this.addRecipe} 
  display={this.state.display} />
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

In home function it directs the page to ('/recipe') that is the file store.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AddRecipe from './addrecipe.js';

var StorePicker = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
  return (
   <form className="store-selector">
    <h2>{recipe.name}</h2> --->//gives error recipe is not defined.
    </form>
   )
 }
 });

export default StorePicker;
```

---

How do I display recipe.name,ingredients,image in the new page given by ('/recipe').There is another file addrecipe.js that creates a form to take the input from user.

This is my index.js file--

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import AddRecipe from './addrecipe';
import StorePicker from './store'; 
import App from './container'

var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router  = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Navigation = ReactRouter.Navigation;
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

var routes = (
  <Router history={createHistory()}>
    <switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/recipe" component={StorePicker} />
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App}/>
    </switch>
 </Router>
    );

  ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Have a look at react "props" https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: What are you using for your router? You can pass an `id` as a param and then use that id to make an api call to fetch the recipe data. Or if you're using redux or some state management you need to pull from their. Need more info about your project.

Comment: I am using react router. Where should I pass the parameter?

Comment: This is index.js file---